# hardcoded domain name fortify issue with google recaptcha api

Tags: javascript, html

I am using google recaptcha v2 in my web application as in [this example](https://www.journaldev.com/7133/how-to-integrate-google-recaptcha-in-java-web-application). Fortify says Hardcoded domain name in HTML. How should handle domain name in script tag of my web page?

Comment: What is the problem with hardcoded domain names?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you've tried so far.

Comment: @Matt EllenRead this https://vulncat.fortify.com/en/detail?id=desc.content.html.hardcoded_domain

Comment: So the problem you're trying to circumvent is someone malicious gaining control of Google's servers? Other than Google, I mean.

Comment: @Brhaka I am using reference to api.js file hosted in google's domain                                  
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>

Comment: @Matt Ellen That's what fortify says.

Answer (score 0):

If your application has a backend (java, php), bring this from backend URL. I managed to resolve my vulnerability this way and the application is working perfectly.